# Can't update grub config inside a chroot

Tags: linux, grub, btrfs, chroot

**Edit: I asked for this to be deleted but it was closed instead..**

I want to edit my GRUB config for a chrooted BTRFS system (/mnt/arch(/@)). I ran these commands:

```
> sudo chroot /mnt/arch/@/
> grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

But I got this error: `/usr/bin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that `/dev` `/proc` and `/sys` are mounted in your chroot. The last two are probably not required but I always mount them just in case.

You can do that by running (**outside** of chroot) this command:

```bsh
for i in /dev /proc /sys; do sudo mount -o bind $i /path/to/chroot${i}; done
```

If I'm not mistaken Arch Linux has a special command which does that automatically but I don't recall its name.

Comment: It is `arch-chroot`

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and the mounted system is arch linux, so I can not use arch-chroot. I tried your commands but I still got the same error.

Comment: What was the exact command that you ran?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls /dev | head` **in chroot**?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the plain `chroot` command and not a distribution-specific wrapper like `arch-chroot`, you'll need to mount the `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` virtual filesystems before chrooting, or else many commands will report strange error conditions as they'll fail to access things they'd need.

On most reasonably modern Linuxes, if the root filesystem that needs fixing is mounted to `/mnt/arch/@/`, the following commands should work:

```
sudo mount -o rbind /dev /mnt/arch/@/dev
sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/arch/@/proc
sudo mount -t sysfs none /mnt/arch/@/sys
sudo chroot /mnt/arch/@
```

To undo the preparations:

```
exit    # = come back out of the chroot
sudo umount /mnt/arch/@/sys
sudo umount /mnt/arch/@/proc
sudo umount /mnt/arch/@/dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Chroot with `arch-chroot`.

```
arch-chroot -a
```

Automatically detects and mount arch partition. Manually

```
arch-chroot /dev/<device name>
```

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and the mounted system is arch linux, so I can not use arch-chroot.